# Cause of Variadic Arguments being corrupted/null

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a wrapper function that allows me to achieve the result of `sprintf` by writing one line of code instead of 3.

```
void output(const tstring& format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    const int len = _vsctprintf(format.c_str(), args) + 1;
    TCHAR* buf = new TCHAR[len];

    _vstprintf(buf, format.c_str(), args);
    OutputDebugString(buf);

    delete[] buf;
}
```

My problem: The variadic arguments are corrupted.

For example;

```
output(_T("%d\n"), 1); // outputs: -858993460
output(_T("%d\n"), 2); // outputs: -858993460
```

Whats the cause of this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you make `format` not a reference, does the problem stop occurring?

Comment: Note that with c++11 and variadic template, you may do `template <typename ... Ts> void outout(const tstring& format, Ts...args) { const int len = _vsctprintf(format.c_str(), args...); std::vector<TCHAR> buf(len); _vstprintf(buf.data(), format.c_str(), args...); OutputDebugString(buf.data()); }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the C++ standard **[support.runtime]**, when discussing the second parameter to `va_start`:

> The parameter *parmN* is the identifier of the rightmost parameter in the variable parameter list of the function deﬁnition (the one just before the `...`). **If the parameter *parmN* is of a reference type**, or of a type that is not compatible with the type that results when passing an argument for which there is no parameter, **the behavior is undeﬁned**.

Emphasis mine. Your `format` parameter is a reference type, hence its use as the last parameter before the `...` results in undefined behavior.